# Dynamically sort NSMutableArray data into NSDictionary alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Unfortunatly I dont currently have internet on my laptop so I will have to describe my code, I have a mutable array of alphabetically sorted song titles. I have a uitableview that is currently displaying these however I want to have section heads and an alphabet index at the side of the table so I need to put these songs into an nsdictionary to display it, however I cant work out an an efficent method of sorting the array into the alphabetical sections (also has a # section, ive made a nsarray of section heads) in the nsdictionary.

Comment: I will upload my code when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities to prepare your data. But since your songs are already sorted your view controller could look something like this:

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sectionTitles;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *songsInSections;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *songs = @[@"A song", @"Another song", @"Some other song", @"Yet another song"];

    // store all the needed section titles
    NSMutableArray *sectionTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
    // store the songs in sections (arrays in array)
    NSMutableArray *songsInSections = [NSMutableArray array];

    // prepare the data for the table view
    for (NSString *song in songs) {
        // get the song's section title (first letter localized and uppercased)
        NSString *sectionTitle = [[song substringToIndex:1] localizedUppercaseString];

        // check if a section for the song's section title has already been created and create one if needed
        if (sectionTitles.count == 0 || ![sectionTitle isEqualToString:sectionTitles[sectionTitles.count - 1]]) {
            // add the section title to the section titles array
            [sectionTitles addObject:sectionTitle];
            // create an (inner) array for the new section
            [songsInSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
        }

        // add the song to the last (inner) array
        [songsInSections[songsInSections.count - 1] addObject:song];
    }

    // "store" the created data to use it as the table view's data source
    self.sectionTitles = sectionTitles;
    self.songsInSections = songsInSections;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.songsInSections count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.sectionTitles[section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.songsInSections[section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.songsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.sectionTitles;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you, with a couple of small modifications this works great!

Comment: Glad I could help. Nevertheless try to be online the next time asking a question to add some more details (and code)... ;)

Comment: My issue is I work as a teacher in Japan, I have loads of time in non-contact periods to code, but no wifi.